# Installation Alert won't go away

Tags: macos, software-update, alert

After a failed installation of updates the following alert won't go away.  It gives me no option to cancel.  Any ideas on how to get rid of it short of rebooting the machine?  Using OSX 10.9.4.

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: you are going to have to reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start `Activity Monitor` (from Launchpad/Other or via Spotlight).

Find `iTunes` in the list and close it. If it's not there then find `iTunes Helper` and close that.

The names are present in the `Process Name` column, closing the processes is possible via the `X` button situated around the top left corner (of course not the red one, which closes the `Activity Monitor` itself, but below that).

Comment: In my case it's Safari, and I'm not running Safari under my login.